# TorBrowser version/OS release matrix

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, linux, mac

I looked everywhere on the Tor Project site and tried to find a document or page that lists the version of TorBrowser and the OS version that it supports. So far, I haven't found anything. I can't imagine I'm the first to ask this question.

Release notes of the various builds don't seem to say anything.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the information and release history seems quite accessible to me.  The download server https://dist.torproject.org/  , https://github.com/torproject/tor ....

Comment: tl;dr "Any reasonably modern desktop operating system", including Windows, Linux and OSX and I think FreeBSD can support it with the option to emulate Linux.

Comment: Yes, the release notes for each version are accessible, but none of them  notes mention something like "This release works on MacOS 10.8" or "This release requires Windows 8.1".  I don't expect this application to require a specific Linux kernel, but it may require specific libraries, etc. which an autogen-like feature during build would check for.

I guess, based on the responses so far, this is going to be one of *those* groups.